# Questions on Backbone.js with Handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js

My backbone.js app with Handelbars does the following.

1. setup a model, its collection, view and router.
2. at the start, get a list of articles from the server and render it using the view via Handlebars.js template.

The code is below.

```
    (function ($) 
    {
      // model for each article
      var Article = Backbone.Model.extend({});

      // collection for articles
      var ArticleCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Article
      });

      // view for listing articles
      var ArticleListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('#main'),
        render: function(){
          var js = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.model.toJSON()));
          var template = Handlebars.compile($("#articles_hb").html());
          $(this.el).html(template(js[0]));
          return this;  
        }
      });

      // main app
      var ArticleApp = Backbone.Router.extend({
        _index: null,
        _articles: null,

        // setup routes
        routes: {
          "" : "index"
        },

        index: function() {
          this._index.render();
        },

        initialize: function() {
          var ws = this;
          if( this._index == null ) {
            $.get('blogs/articles', function(data) {
              var rep_data = JSON.parse(data);
              ws._articles = new ArticleCollection(rep_data);
              ws._index = new ArticleListView({model: ws._articles});
              Backbone.history.loadUrl();
          });               
          return this;
        }
        return this;
      }
    });

    articleApp = new ArticleApp();
  })(jQuery);
```

Handlebars.js template is

```
<script id="articles_hb" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  {{#articles}}
    {{title}}
  {{/articles}}
</script>
```

The above code works fine and it prints article titles. However, my question is

1. When passing context to Handlebars.js template, I am currently doing `$(this.el).html(template(js[0]))`. Is this the right way? When I do just "js" instead of  js[0], the JSON object has leading and ending square brackets. Hence it recognizes as a array object of JSON object. So I had to js[0]. But I feel like it isn't a proper solution.
2. When I first create the "View", I am creating it like below.

   ws._index = new ArticleListView({model: ws._articles});

But in my case, I should do

```
ws._index = new ArticleListView({collection: ws._articles});
```

Shouldn't I? (I was following a tutorial btw). Or does this matter? I tried both, and it didn't seem to make much difference.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how can i include this handlebar.js template into my html

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It seems like you are creating a view for a collection so you *should* initialize your view using `collection` instead of `model`.

As far as handlebars, I haven't used it a lot but I think you want to do something like this:

```
var ArticleListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#main'),
    render: function(){
      var js = this.collection.toJSON();
      var template = Handlebars.compile($("#articles_hb").html());
      $(this.el).html(template({articles: js}));
      return this;  
    }
  });
```

and then use something like this for the template

```
  {{#each articles}}
    {{this.title}}
  {{/each}}
```

p.s. the line 
`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.model.toJSON()))` is equivalent to `this.model.toJSON()`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

```
var ArticleListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        this.template = Handlebars.compile($('#articles_hb').html());
    },
    render: function(){
      $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
      return this;  
    }
  });
```

/////////////////////////////////////

```
ws._index = new ArticleListView({model: ws._articles});
```